# Eclipse debugger is arbitrarily disconnecting

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm building an Android app with 5 activities and one application (pseudo-singleton) containing a chunk of ndk code. I've recently added a few routines in the ndk, all of which are stable, but since then my app has been acting erratically: my singleton seems to reset, and my activity goes back a level for reasons I have yet to figure out. One of the things that's hindering my understanding is that the debugger is disconnecting. No warning, no "source not found" message... poof! gone!

Has anyone come across this problem? Any advice?

***EDIT:***

I've added the Logcat of the event when attached to my phone (Nexus S). It records a crash, but still don't know why:

```
06-22 15:09:26.469: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10791): GC_CONCURRENT freed 683K, 53% free    3181K/6663K, external 2055K/2137K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-22 15:09:27.324: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Displayed edu.upenn.jime.infApp/.ShowPlot: +1s7ms
06-22 15:09:31.418: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Start proc com.whatsapp for service com.whatsapp/.messaging.MessageService: pid=10889 uid=10092 gids={1015, 3003}
06-22 15:09:32.195: INFO/DEBUG(10706): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-22 15:09:32.195: INFO/DEBUG(10706): Build fingerprint: 'google/soju/crespo:2.3.4/GRJ22/121341:user/release-keys'
06-22 15:09:32.195: INFO/DEBUG(10706): pid: 10791, tid: 10791  >>> edu.upenn.jime.infApp <<<
06-22 15:09:32.195: INFO/DEBUG(10706): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000020
06-22 15:09:32.199: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  r0 00000000  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000000  r3 00000008
06-22 15:09:32.199: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  r4 000619a8  r5 421bb214  r6 00000000  r7 ffffffff
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  r8 00000008  r9 bed3d540  10 fffffe84  fp fffffe84
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  ip 80043c41  sp bed3d440  lr 80031cac  pc 80043c52  cpsr 60000030
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d0  000000000000037c  d1  00000040bed3d300
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d2  0049002e00690000  d3  0066007200750000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000100000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d6  0000000000000001  d7  0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d8  3fd0d32894e2c335  d9  0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d16 000000c240038350  d17 c053000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.203: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 8000000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 ff00000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d24 ff00000000000000  d25 ff00000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d26 0100010001000100  d27 0100010001000100
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 3ff0000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
06-22 15:09:32.215: INFO/DEBUG(10706):  scr 2000001a
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):          #00  pc 00043c52  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):          #01  pc 00031ca8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): code around pc:
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80043c30 f9daf7ff e9c39b02 20010100 bf00bd10 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80043c40 41f0e92d 68004605 4c1a4698 b08a460f 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80043c50 6a034616 0599447c 2302d501 2301e000 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80043c60 3008f88d fa62f7ff c04cf8df 17fb463a 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80043c70 2308e9cd 95062200 300cf854 4330f8d3 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): code around lr:
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80031c8c e59d1078 e1a00008 ebffbc84 e3e01000 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80031c9c e3a03008 e1a02000 e59d0020 eb01551e 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80031cac eaffde80 e1a0200a e1a03005 e1a00008 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80031cbc e1a01004 e58d6000 ebffdb3d eaffdea9 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): 80031ccc e59d2024 e7913002 e5931370 e3510000 
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706): stack:
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d400  bed3d458  
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d404  00000000  
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d408  bed3d4e8  
06-22 15:09:32.285: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d40c  4214ce14  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d410  bed3d438  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d414  4214ce0c  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d418  fffffe84  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d41c  ad34675f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d420  00000000  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d424  0000037c  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d428  0011da48  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d42c  ad34676b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d430  bed3d458  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d434  80017e38  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d438  df002777  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d43c  e3a070ad  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706): #00 bed3d440  bed3d4e8  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d444  4214ce08  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d448  0000ce60  
06-22 15:09:32.289: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d44c  00000001  
06-22 15:09:32.293: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d450  bed3d4e8  
06-22 15:09:32.293: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d454  80049697  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-22 15:09:32.293: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d458  4214ce08  
06-22 15:09:32.293: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d45c  431f2903  
06-22 15:09:32.301: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d460  ad346761  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-22 15:09:32.301: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d464  bed3d4e8  
06-22 15:09:32.301: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d468  42f8b182  
06-22 15:09:32.301: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d46c  4214cdf4  
06-22 15:09:32.301: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d470  0000ce60  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d474  4214ce08  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d478  421bb31c  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d47c  80031cac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706): #01 bed3d480  421bb214  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d484  0000000c  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d488  4214ccf0  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d48c  40167900  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d490  27cabd5f  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d494  00000135  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d498  4060be80  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d49c  800a5600  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4a0  421bb214  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4a4  fffffe84  
06-22 15:09:32.304: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4a8  40016d08  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4ac  0004dbd8  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4b0  00000015  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4b4  00000000  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4b8  0000ae20  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4bc  800a3588  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4c0  800a3588  
06-22 15:09:32.308: INFO/DEBUG(10706):     bed3d4c4  800a3588  
06-22 15:09:32.660: INFO/BootReceiver(115): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-22 15:09:32.676: INFO/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{40a80190 edu.upenn.jime.infApp/edu.upenn.jime.infApp.Simulate paused=false}
06-22 15:09:32.676: INFO/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{409996b8 edu.upenn.jime.infApp/edu.upenn.jime.infApp.Inf paused=false}
06-22 15:09:32.676: INFO/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{40a6d0c8 edu.upenn.jime.infApp/edu.upenn.jime.infApp.CalcInf paused=false}
06-22 15:09:32.679: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Process edu.upenn.jime.infApp (pid 10791) has died.
06-22 15:09:32.691: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Start proc edu.upenn.jime.infApp for activity edu.upenn.jime.infApp/.CalcInf: pid=10901 uid=10118 gids={}
06-22 15:09:32.699: DEBUG/Zygote(75): Process 10791 terminated by signal (11)
06-22 15:09:32.793: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10901): Trying to load lib /data/data/edu.upenn.jime.infApp/lib/libinfApp.so 0x40514540
06-22 15:09:32.801: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10901): Added shared lib /data/data/edu.upenn.jime.infApp/lib/libinfApp.so 0x40514540
06-22 15:09:32.801: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10901): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/edu.upenn.jime.infApp/lib/libinfApp.so 0x40514540, skipping init
06-22 15:09:32.859: WARN/InputManagerService(115): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 10791 uid 10118
06-22 15:09:32.937: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Displayed edu.upenn.jime.infApp/.CalcInf: +253ms
06-22 15:09:33.140: INFO/dalvikvm(10889): Could not find method android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.captureFrame, referenced from method com.whatsapp.u5.a
06-22 15:09:33.140: WARN/dalvikvm(10889): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 428: Landroid/media/MediaMetadataRetriever;.captureFrame ()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;
06-22 15:09:33.140: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10889): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x012f
06-22 15:09:33.148: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10889): VFY: dead code 0x0132-0138 in Lcom/whatsapp/u5;.a (Landroid/app/Activity;Lcom/whatsapp/am;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;BLjava/lang/String;)Z
06-22 15:09:34.957: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10889): GC_CONCURRENT freed 846K, 50% free 3406K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 10ms+3ms
```

I should also mention that the code was working fine up until I added a couple more routines in the NDK(went from 5 to 7) that link with the GSL library. The routines execute fine and return correct data, and the crash does not always happen immediately after their execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a fair bit of effort but I figured out the issue: I passed an array to ndk which was too small for the function. Instead of throwing a Seg fault then and there, it kept on humming for a few more minutes, or even hours. Then suddenly the whole application collapses with no warning and the last working intent gets loaded.

This was a real pain as the tombstone/stacktrace gave no useful information. Unlike a typical seg fault in Java/Android, the screen displays nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

are you outputting to the log? A lot of time when the debugger detaches its due to null reference!

if that isn't the issue, i would suggest deleting the current emulator and creating a new one. sometimes they can get buggy and this usually gives you a fresh state to work with.